# Traço embaixo da pagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou tentando colocar um traço embaixo da pagina atual como na imagem.

[image: Como deve ficar]

Preciso fazer isso com o jQuery, não é uma opção colocar um `border-bottom` em cada pagina aberta. Pensei em pegar a `url` da pagina e se for igual a alguma classe (que vou atribuir ao botão) ele adiciona o estilo de `border-bottom` então. Estou meio perdido e não sei como começar ou o melhor método, só pensei nesse da url mas não sei como executar ainda.

Comment: Você já tem algum código feito? Assim fica mais fácil para te ajudar.

Comment: Não, pois como disse não tenho ideia por onde começar e nem sei se o método que disse é o mais simples.

Comment: Comece pesquisando como obter a URL com JavaScript; depois estude a sintaxe do `if` e veja como fazer comparações; pesquise como alterar uma classe CSS via jQuery e, finalmente, escreva a classe CSS que define a borda. Se não conseguir alguma parte, pode voltar e [edit] a pergunta com mais detalhes. Boa sorte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma opção é você pegar a url com location e dar um split(dividir) nela por "/" e pegar a ultima parte e comparar com os campos:

```js
var url = window.location.href;
var urlSplit = url.split("/");
var pagina = urlSplit[urlSplit.length-1];
console.log(pagina);

//aqui você compara a página com seu menu e marca o ativo
```